# [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview, nsmutablearray

i'm experiencing an error

> [__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15580c90
>   2014-02-18 15:10:49.490 CIB[1706:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15580c90'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x2da18e83 0x37d756c7 0x2da1c7b7 0x2da1b0af 0x2d969dc8 0x2e33b695 0x2e33b169 0x301ab2fd 0x1603ad 0x302cf315 0x302776cd 0x30276ef1 0x3019d353 0x2fe23943 0x2fe1f167 0x2fe1eff9 0x2fe1ea0d 0x2fe1e81f 0x2fe1854d 0x2d9e3f69 0x2d9e18f7 0x2d9e1c43 0x2d94c471 0x2d94c253 0x326862eb 0x30201845 0x113de1 0x3826eab7)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

I have loop here. from array in Json to my model tasklist then stored to NSMutableArray _tasklist

```
NSArray *taskJson = [json objectForKey:@"fOTaskListModelWss"];

    for (NSDictionary *dictCQ in taskJson) {
        NSLog(@"TASKLIST: %@", [dictCQ objectForKey:@"foTaskListModelWs"]);

        NSDictionary *datadic = [dictCQ objectForKey:@"foTaskListModelWs"];
        TaskList *task = [[TaskList alloc]init];
        [task setTaskCount:datadic[@"count"]];
        [task setFuncCd:datadic[@"funcCd"]];
        [task setFuncCdDscp:datadic[@"funcCdDscp"]];
        [task setRequestStatus:datadic[@"requestStatus"]];
        [task setRole:datadic[@"role"]];
        [_taskList addObject:task];
    }
```

then here is my code in cellForRowAtRowPathIndex

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString * simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuTableViewCell";
MenuTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
TaskList *txn = [_taskList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.titleLabel.text = txn.funcCdDscp;
cell.totalCountLabel.text = txn.taskCount;
return cell;}
```

Comment: check your table numberofrowsection

Comment: Do you put breakpoint on your table numberofrowsection and cellForRowAtIndexPath method in which method error occured?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
cell.titleLabel.text = txn.funcCdDscp;
cell.totalCountLabel.text = txn.taskCount;
```

One of these (not sure which, but my guess would be `taskCount`) is a NSNumber. Text takes an NSString.

Comment: Perfect. Look for all your DB objects that are loading the UILabel.text. One of them may be a NSNumber.

Comment: Solve Issue MyProblem is that I send the parameters all string but one is Int dataType Thats way my app is crashing .......

Answer (score 19):

```
cell.titleLabel.text = txn.funcCdDscp;
cell.totalCountLabel.text = [txn.taskCount stringValue];
```

OR

Use this as this is `best solution`

```
cell.totalCountLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",txn.taskCount];
```

Answer (score 5):

Hope the following will help you if you are manipulating JSON data from webservice

```
cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[JsonDictionaryObject objectForKey:@"Respected_Key_Name"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 4):

Here it is expecting `NSString` instead of `NSNumber` so that is the reason it crashes.So convert that to `NSString` then it will be resolved.